# Using an image as a sidebar background in lieu of a color

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use an image as a sidebar background for links in stead of a color?

The image I wish to use is a crop of the banner used and will make it appear more seamless than using a color. Any help would be appreciated.

FYI- I am A novice. Below is what I tried :

```
.sidebar {
    float: left;
    height:100%;
    width:15%;
    background:<img src="web_images/sidebar.png"/>;
    padding-top:5%; 
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
   .sidebar {
    float: left;
    height:100%;
    width:15%;
    background:url("web_images/sidebar.png");
    padding-top:5%; 
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size:14px;
```

}

Comment: good stuff,looking at it now its something that seems obvious. Thanks for your help.